# How do you create multithreading function in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

My project asked me to create a multithreading function, and it allows up to 1000 threads. How do you do that in java?

I know we can do that by implementing the `Runnable` interface or creating a subclass to extends `Thread`, but I don't know if you can create such a large number of threads.

Comment: You know how to create one thread. If you know how loops work in Java, then you know how to create a variable number of threads in a loop. Make a loop that runs 1000 times and creates and starts a thread each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple threads using a loop in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884771/how-to-create-multiple-threads-using-a-loop-in-java)

Comment: What did your homework specifically ask for?

Comment: @Goion That question is not a duplicate, because it is about a problem with sharing a variable between multiple threads, not about creating multiple threads itself.

Answer (score 3):

**try this**

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class main {
private static JFrame frame;
private static JButton button;
main(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    button = new JButton("Click");
    button.setBounds(20,20,2,2);
    button.addActionListener(multi(frame));
    frame.setSize(200,200);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new main();
    }
    private static ActionListener multi (Component GTOS) {
        return (ae) -> {
            new Thread(() -> {
                System.out.println("test");
            }).start();
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `ExecutorService`. For example, it might look like this:

```
public void myMethod() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
    List<Callable<Boolean>> callableList = new ArrayList<Callable<Boolean>>();      
    // any list for init our threads
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        callableList.add(() -> exec()); 
    executor.invokeAll(callableList);
}

public boolean exec() {
    // do something
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code isn't great for a number of reasons, but it does show you a way to create 1,000 threads:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
    new Thread("thread " + n).start();
}
```